# Rails - Populate test database with development data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rake

Is there any trivial way to copy the data from developmenet database into the test one? I know theres a way to copy schema and recreate database, but is there any rake task to populate test database with development one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use mysql directly:

```
mysqldump app_development | mysql app_test
```

Comment: if your not using mysql, @j0k has best answer so far with: rake db:test:clone && rake db:seed RAILS_ENV='test'

Answer (score 14):

You can use:

```
rake db:test:clone
```

To copy the development db into test.

Comment: Doesn't work for me at all. Structure is created, but no records are copied. Is that task ment to copy the data at all? The description isn't pointing that directly.

Comment: db:test:clone is a combination of db:schema:dump and db:test:prepare and does not actually copy the *data*

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I was exactly what I was looking for, copying the structure and not the data (I delete the data in tests anyway)

Comment: this is deprecated.

Comment: @mdrozdziel, the test db should never have and data, the data should be created for each test.

Answer (score 6):

For all databases:

```
rake db:test:clone && rake db:seed RAILS_ENV='test'
```

Comment: ops, i thought that you wanted to populate test database with the seed.rb file.

Answer (score 6):

With Postgres, copy the database like so:

> CREATE DATABASE newdb WITH TEMPLATE originaldb OWNER dbuser;

Comment: I didn't use this command but it helped create a copy of the db using pgAdmin.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to clone the development DB in its entirety, what's wrong with just copying the development.sqlite3 and renaming it test.sqlite3?  You can automate the process by setting up a batch file (or its equivalent on your OS) that you can run from the command line.

This will work locally, but I just realized you might be thinking a non-local environment, in which case it probably won't.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative method if you use seeds (db/seeds.rb)

First, add a rake task for example to lib/tasks/test_seed.rake with this code:

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    task :prepare => :environment do
        Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

Then whenever you changed your database structure / content through migration and seeds, you can run

```
rake:db:test:prepare
```

To copy the schema and seed data.

So the complete steps would be:

```
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
rake db:test:prepare
```

Comment: If you run `rake db:test:prepare` after `rake db:seed` it will delete your seed data =]