# this method is not working in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Im building a class using an ActiveRecord-table as datafeed with 46 items inside
I dont understand the problem here, **it seems like I can't extract the items in a new array?**

**This is my Rspec-result:**

Failures:

```
  1) TrainSearch :rows has 46 items
     Failure/Error: expect(checker.data).to eq(46)

       expected: 46
            got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

       (compared using ==)
```

This is my code:

```
class TrainSearch

    attr_reader :data

    def initialize
      @data = Timetable.all
    end

    def rows
      @rows ||= @data.map {|row| Row.new(row)}
    end
end
```

**HERE IS MY CODE:** [file](https://github.com/yonipacheko/train_check/blob/master/spec/models/train_search_spec.rb)

Thanks for yr time!

Comment: Aren't you comparing an array to a number?
Shouldn't you have `expect(checker.data.size).to eq(46)`

Comment: @Baloo Hi there! if I do like u suggested I get this: 1) TrainSearch :rows has 46 items
     Failure/Error: expect(checker.data.size).to eq(46)

       expected: 46
            got: 0

Answer (score 0):

What Baloo pointed out in the comments seems pretty much the case. Your error message explicitly tells you what its comparing.

Without seeing the code itself, it is a little bit harder to interpret but here goes.

You are querying some record in the database (rows?) and expecting there to be 46 of them. 
Your query returns an ActiveRecord relation (an array of all the rows). To figure out how many rows there are you need to do:

```
checker.data.count
```

It seems you also have another error which I can't track down from the given information. Your query is returning an empty array so that count is going to be 0 and will still fail.

Comment: @jjkeuhlen that's correct Im getting nil too but why? the timetable db is full with obj:s

Comment: Which database is full? Could your problem be that you are attempting to test data created in the development database rather than the test database (they are separate databases)?

Comment: hey that's correct my data is created in the dev.section. Now I thought that using 'rake db:test:prepare' I create a clone of my regular DB?

Comment: I think that only copies the data if the data was initially created using the ./config/seeds.rb file? I may be wrong there. Take a look at [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645022/rails-populate-test-database-with-development-data) question or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693365/whats-the-difference-between-dbtestclone-dbtestclone-structure-dbtestlo) for more information there.